# Mutex Across Threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, callback, network-programming, mutex

So, I am getting an exception with the code below. I have put the exception details with it, but I believe it is caused by the fact that a different thread releases the lock then the one that starts the lock. I want to do this to potentially allow my main thread to continue while the writes queue up and occur.

First and foremost, I want to know if there IS a way this can be done? Secondly, should this be done or is it a bad plan?  have looked at ManualResetEvent, Monitor and Mutex all of which seem to do this. Note, this is for a network server and it is my first time writing a multithreaded, potentially high traffic one.

Exception: Thrown the first time a send (and its callback) is called.

> System.ApplicationException on mutex.ReleaseMutex(). "Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code."

```
public void SendAsync(byte[] packet)
{
    mutex.WaitOne();
    client.GetStream().BeginWrite(packet, 0, packet.Length, WriteCallback, null);
}

private void WriteCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    client.GetStream().EndWrite(ar);
    mutex.ReleaseMutex();

    Console.WriteLine("Sent Data to " + RemoteEndPoint);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering this -

> I want to do this to potentially allow my main thread to continue while the writes queue up and occur.
>
> First and foremost, I want to know if there IS a way this can be done?

I don't think you need a `mutex` for that. Are you looking for something like this -

```
static object _lock = new object(); //somewhere based on your context
public void SendAsync(byte[] packet)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ..... other codes
            lock (_lock)
            {
                client.GetStream().BeginWrite(packet, 0, packet.Length, 
                ar => // the write callback (lambda)
                {
                    client.GetStream().EndWrite(ar);
                    Console.WriteLine("Sent Data to " + RemoteEndPoint);
                }, null);
            }
        });
}
```

Explanation:

1. `Task.Run` runs asynchronously in a threadpool, which keeps your main thread free all the time.
2. `lock(_lock)`  ensures only one thread is writing to the stream at any single moment, (threads are spawned by the `threadpool` from `Task.Run`)
3. You don't need a separate `writecallback`, you could use inline `lambda callback` methods. Makes life much easier.

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: This doesn't seems to be a good design, Here a Task, which makes execution Asynchronous, is using a lock to synchronize for a shared resource, thus restricting the working of all tasks across processors and internally it is making a call again to another asynchronous method, which reply on IAsyncResult to show the result

Comment: That's because - OP wants -  "I want to do this to potentially allow my main thread to continue while the writes queue up and occur." . Without the lock the stream will have unexpected outputs.

Comment: I think this is essentially what I asked for though. I may be naive, but why is this inefficient? This only makes the calls synchronized because the could never technically work simultaneously. The goal is really just to get this to work asynchronously with other code.

Comment: It will achieve the goal, but as you need to design for a high traffic system, a lock inside a task, which will block all other tasks, will lead to very high contention considerably reducing the performance. Tasks are good enough to make things asynchronous, bare minimum you can do is only lock the part where stream is written, that too only if it is absolutely required, else it defeats the purpose. Check if you can do some data parallelization and can achieve the target without synchronization construct like lock, mutex

Comment: You are right, but you might have miss interpreted the code, because his code  only has the stream writer code. There was no other codes to organize the calls. But for future I will update the code.

Comment: @user3812869 Mrinal has a point - if you expect a lot of parallel calls to SendAsync then with the above solution you are risking to end up with the high lock contention and hence degraded performance. You may want to redesign the code in such way that every thread works with its own instance of `client`- thus eliminating the need of locking.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone! I will look into to all of it, but I'm not quite sure how I can avoid using a lock entirely as these threads will share resources, but maybe I can minimize

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using Mutex class, according to Microsoft

> The Mutex class enforces thread identity, so a mutex can be released only by the thread that acquired it. By contrast, the Semaphore class does not enforce thread identity. A mutex can also be passed across application domain boundaries.

I think, your callback method is called from another thread, it causes the Exception.
As suggested by Microsoft, you can use Semaphore for this situation.

For example:

```
static volatile Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1,1);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(fn2));
        oThread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        sem.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("Main is Doing");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        sem.Release();
    }
    static void fn2()
    {
        sem.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("Thread is Doing");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        sem.Release();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I tried that, but I'll give it another shot for experimentation purposes.